# При парсинге файлов теряется расширение файлов

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

нужно спарсить около 200 файлов. 
Возможные расширения файлов: pdf (как в примере), а также doc, docx и прочие текстовые и графические вплоть до jpg.

Данный тестовый код сохраняет файл с нужным мне именем, но теряет расширение.

```
import requests, shutil, os
s= link_to_contruct
filename = order_num 
r = requests.get(s, stream=True, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

получается файл с именем, заданным переменной  filename.

**Вопрос: Подскажите, как вытянуть из запроса по [ссылке](http://zakupki.gov.ru/44fz/filestore/public/1.0/download/rgk2/file.html?uid=7F8D1FFA650000B8E0530A86120DE127) расширение файла?**

*P.S. Понимаю, что в процессе кода я просто срезаю имя, но не могу понять, как мне его воспринять в программе в переменную или ещё куда...*

Answer (score 2):

Довольно часто ссылки оканчиваются именем файла, тогда расширение получается простым отделением от точки:

```
ext = s.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
```

Опять же сервер может передать mime-type в заголовке `Content-Type`

Кроме того, может присутствовать заголовок `Content-Disposition` в котором указывается имя файла.

Т. е. полный алгоритм следующий:

1. Если есть заголовок `Content-Disposition` берём имя файла оттуда и получаем расширение.
2. Если расширения нет - анализируем заголовок `Content-Type` и выставляем по расширение по нему.
3. Если расширения нет - пытаемся вытащить из ссылки - если там есть точка.

Comment: По поводу примера - да, это был бы самым простым вариантом, о к сожалению, дается ссылка на файл без его наименования:-( Можете подсказать как вызвать Content-Disposition и Content-Type кодом? или хотя бы где искать?

Comment: У объекта ответа есть свойство headers - там перечислены все заголовки ответа.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, я решил проблему иначе. 
На данном конкретно сайте в этом .... дивизионе?..:

```
<a class="" href="http://zakupki.gov.ru/44fz/filestore/public/1.0/download/rgk2/file.html?uid=810B895A2F0A0018E0530A86120D9AAB" title="Контракт 29-2019.docx (44.72 Кб)">
                                                                Контракт 29-201...

                                                                     № 15112000128190000290002

                                                            </a>
```

есть атрибуты href и title. 
Соответственно, получив нужный участок кода html, я по очереди обращаюсь к этим атрибутам при помощи метода .get:

```
contruct_div = soup.find_all('a', class_='')[2] 
link_to_contruct = contruct_div.get('href')
file_name = contruct_div.get('title') <i> # Контракт 29-2019.docx (44.72 Кб) <i>
```

Из имени я регуляркой собираюсь вынуть расширение файла. Всё оказалось просто:-)